# Client verification

Tags: security, authentication, networking, client-server, secret-key

Let's say that we have two machines machine one and machine two:

- machine one has a static IP.
- machine two has a dynamic IP.

now machine two wants to connect to machine one. how could machine one verify that the other machine is machine two?

I am searching for a scalable solution so I could use it for a server that has a number of clients.

my solution is to use a key which is already known by the two machines.

machine two will try to connect to machine one. which will respond with a randomly generated string,
that machine two will encrypt using the known key. and sends it back to machine one, which can check if the encrypted string is encrypted with the correct key.

my solution is easily scalable, but I am not sure if it is secure enough. is there a standard solution for doing this??

Comment: Look into two-way/mutual TLS.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there but if you were to rely on this alone you'd be at risk of a man in the middle attack. Say a malicious machine 3 is pretending to be machine 1.

- Machine 2 tries to connect to machine 1 but instead opens a connection with machine 3.
- Machine 3 opens a connection with machine 1, machine 1 responds with
  a string "encrypt_me_please"
- Machine 3 responds to machine 2's connection request with
  "encrypt_me_please"
- Machine 2 encrypts "encrypt_me_please" as (say) "x10hsdapg" and sends
  it back to machine 3
- Machine 3 responds to machine 1 with the encrypted string "x10hsdapg"
- Machine 1 verifies that Machine 3 used the correct encryption key and therefore must be machine 2.

All you can really establish with this is that machine 2 is on the network. But, in a sense that's all you really can do. What I mean is that you can never really be certain that the host you're connected to is who they say they are on an unsecured network. But what we can do is employ various cryptographic techniques so that messages we send can only be decrypted by their intended recipient. See for e.g., RSA.

I hope that helps at least, I'll admit its been a few years since I've studied cryptography.